# script reading from new descriptor in read

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, tty, file-descriptors

I have a script that asks some questions to the user and repeats the question until the user has answered something appropiate. This is done with an infinite loop that is `break`'d when an acceptable answer is read:

```
while true
do
    read -p "Which helper do you prefer (cache, store)? " HELPER
    if [ "$HELPER" = "store" -o "$HELPER" = "cache" ]
    then
        break
    else
        error "Invalid option. Choose again"
    fi
done
```

This is working fine when called independently. The problem is when I execute this script inside a `| while read ...` loop:

```
# find scripts that should be run as non-root user, and run them all sequentially
grep -l '^\s*require_non_root' [0-9]* | while read execScript
do
  echo "=== EXECUTING $execScript ==="
  "./$execScript"
done
```

The ouptut of the `grep` command alone is what should be in my case:

```
15-gitcredentials
20-workspace
40-download_latest_dev_vapp
99-change_username_and_password
```

## Problem:

the `15-gitcredentials` script (the first snip I posted is part of this script) is reading the same `STDIN` that the `| while read execScript` part is expected to read, i.e. the output of the grep command. How could I made the `15-gitcredentials` script to read not from `STDIN` but from other descriptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching the problem with the wrong solution.

```
for p in $(grep -l regex files); do
    echo -n "Executing $p ... "
    ./$p
    echo "[DONE]"
done
```